# JavaFx: including a picture to the left side of a border pane

Tags: java, javafx

I will show the code first.

```
public class prog_aufgabe_2_2 extends Application {



@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws FileNotFoundException {

        ///Create BorderPane + add toolbar and Buttons 
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        Button b1 = new Button("open");
        Button b2 = new Button("save");
        Button b3 = new Button("saveAs");
        ToolBar toolBar1 = new ToolBar(); /// Create toolbar align to top
        toolBar1.getItems().addAll(b1,b2,b3); /// Add Buttons to toolbar


        borderPane.setTop(toolBar1);

        ///Image left

        Image image1 = new Image(new FileInputStream("C:\Users\dimi1\Desktop\DMM\Programmiertechniken yi\JavaFx Bilder"));
        ImageView img1 = new ImageView();
        img1.setImage(image1);
        borderPane.setLeft(img1);


        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(borderPane, 300, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

So, I tried adding a picture and align it to the left side of a Borderpane. When I run the code , the following erros occur:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

    at Woche_5.prog_aufgabe_2_2.start(prog_aufgabe_2_2.java:33)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application Woche_5.prog_aufgabe_2_2
```

So, here is what I think happens. Simply...,it can't find the path of the picture. Also, in the error message they want me to change the path of

```
Image image1 = new Image(new FileInputStream("C:\Users\dimi1\Desktop\DMM\Programmiertechniken yi\JavaFx Bilder"));
```

and change all \ to / .

What is causing the problem and how can I align a picture to the left side ?

Comment: "Also, in the error message they want me to change ... all \ to / ". So did you try that?

Comment: Yes, did not work

Comment: I think, it has something to do with the way how I add the image. If there are different methods on how to implement pictures. That would be great.         I just copied the path into new FileInputStream("....) from the properties of the picture.

Comment: Your path appears to be a directory, not an image file.  Image file names usually have extension like `.png` or `.jpg`.

Comment: Ok, I added:                                                                                                                                Image image1 = new Image((new FileInputStream("file:///C:/Users/dimi1/Desktop/DMM/Programmiertechniken%20yi/JavaFx%20Bilder/funny-snapchat-face-swaps-261__605.jpg")));                And I am still getting errors.